# Running multiple commands in a command line utility using cmd.exe from .Net win form

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, tableau-api

I want to run [tabcmd.exe utility](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm) to publish views in tableau server. Manual step to do this is as follows, log file will be updated for every step in the location

> "C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Tableau\tabcmd.log"

In the same session I have to perform this steps manually one by one order

1. Run cmd.exe
2. log in by using the command **tabcmd login -s "http:/sales-server:8000" -t Sales -u administrator -p p@ssw0rd!**
3. Create Project Name using the command **tabcmd createproject -n "Quarterly_Reports" -d "Workbooks showing quarterly sales reports."**
4. Publish views by using the command **tabcmd publish "analysis.twbx" -n "Sales_Analysis" --db-user "jsmith" --db-password "p@ssw0rd"**
5. Refresh by using the command **tabcmd refreshextracts --workbook "My Workbook"**
6. Log out by using the command **tabcmd logout**

Now I am trying to automate this steps from my .Net win form, so I used below code as a try and It is not working.

```
String path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tableau\Tableau Server\7.0\bin\tabcmd.exe"
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ();
startInfo.FileName = "\""+path+ "\"";
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format("login -s http://Server1:8000 --db-user "jsmith" --db-password "p@ssw0rd");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false ;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();      


using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("createproject -n \"MyProject\" -d \"MyProjectWorkbook\"");
                //sw.WriteLine("My next Command");
                //sw.WriteLine("My next Command");
            }
        }
```

I am able to log in successfully and I am not able to proceed consequent steps further, I have no clue how to proceed on this further, so I am looking forward some help on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redirecting output but not actually reading it is a bad idea.  The program will just hang when its output buffer is full and can't be emptied because you are not reading it.  Happens quickly too, usually around 2 kilobytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is of use to you or not but you could try creating a batch file with all of those commands and the execute the batch file from command prompt like this :-

```
  //Build Commands - You may have to play with the syntax

    string[] cmdBuilder = new string[5] 
      { 
       @"tabcmd login -s 'http:/sales-server:8000' -t Sales -u administrator -p p@ssw0rd!",
       @"tabcmd createproject -n 'Quarterly_Reports' -d 'Workbooks showing quarterly sales reports.'",
       @"abcmd publish 'analysis.twbx' -n 'Sales_Analysis' --db-user 'jsmith' --db-password 'p@ssw0rd'", 
       @"tabcmd refreshextracts workbook 'My Workbook'",
       @"tabcmd logout"

      };


     //Create a File Path

    string BatFile = @"\YourLocation\tabcmd.bat";

    //Create Stream to write to file.

    StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(BatFile);

     foreach (string cmd in cmdBuilder) 
        { 
          sWriter.WriteLine(cmd); 
        }

       sWriter.Close();

    //Run your Batch File & Remove it when finished.


   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cmd.exe";
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\YourLocation\tabcmd.bat";
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit();
   File.Delete(@"\YourLocation\tabcmd.bat")
```

I'll leave the output section to yourself. You could try this, it is not exactly clean but will automate the main steps. It's either this, or opening a process for each command as the last process exits?

Hope this is of help.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you suggest here. p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\YourLocation\tabcmd.bat";

Comment: You build the batch file, then save it to a location, when you start the Process to run the batch file, the argument points to this file so that when cms.exe launches it runs teh batch file.

Comment: If I run the batch file manually it works fine, but if the run it through code, nothing is happening.

Comment: p.StartInfo.Arguments is not required and just p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\YourLocation\tabcmd.bat"; is enough